# Integral of $f'$ where $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable over $(a,b)$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

There is a problem which states that if $f$ is a function continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable almost everywhere on $(a,b)$ whose $|\text{Diff}_\frac{1}{n} f| \leq g$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$ for all $n$, $g$ integrable over $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f' = f(b) - f(a)$.

I seem to have proven that $\int_{a}^{b} f' < f(b) - f(a)$ by the Integral Comparison Test.

Is the Mean Value Theorem helpful in proving the other side of the inequality? It's what the first two statements seem to lead to.

Comment: I don't know what that $1/n$ subscript means, and you have introduced the symbol $g$ without letting us in on what you mean by it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $\text{Diff}_{\frac{1}{n}} f(x) = \frac{f(x+ \frac{1}{n}) + f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$. $g$ is a function integrable over $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks. But surely that should be $f(x+n^{-1})-f(x)$ in the numerator? And "all $n$" means "all non-zero integers $n$"? or maybe "all positive integers $n$"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes the numerator is correct. $n$ is a natural number. The integral is a Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I might think about things:

1. The condition $|\text{Diff}_{\frac{1}{n}}(f)| \leq g$ for some integrable $g$ is very much suggestive to use Dominated Convergence. This gives you the equality $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{a}^{b-\frac{1}{n}}\text{Diff}_{\frac{1}{n}}(f) = \int_{a}^{b}f'$.
2. Now the focus is to show $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{a}^{b-\frac{1}{n}}\text{Diff}_{\frac{1}{n}}(f) = f(b) - f(a)$. I might try to rewrite the integral and make use of [Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), which says, for example, $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\delta\int_{a}^{a + \delta}f = f(a)$.

Comment: It seems that Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem requires $f$ to be absolutely continuous.

Comment: No, it just needs locally integrable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to use these.